# AWS SNS Delivery retry policy Total policy retry time cannot be greater than 3600 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying the AWS SNS Delivery retry policy to have it retry every 1 hour for 10 hours.

This is my setup.

[This is my setup for the SNS delivery policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hyOS.png)

But I am having an error that it says:

> Couldn't set topic delivery retry policy.
> Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: An error occurred while setting the attribute delivery retry policy (http/s). Invalid parameter: DeliveryPolicy: http.defaultHealthyRetryPolicy: Total policy retry time cannot be greater than 3600 seconds

I have tried making the values around 1500-3599 and making sure that the `Minimum delay` is lesser than the `Maximum delay`.

It only works when the values are within 20-120 (or a few hundreds but definitely not 999)

Anyone here who has been successful setting it up at every hour retry? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it says on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy:

> The total policy retry time for an HTTP/S endpoint cannot be greater than 3,600 seconds. This is a hard limit and cannot be increased.

This means that you cannot create a retry policy which is longer than an hour.